# python zipfile.ZipFile() method generates 20G zip file from 6M original

Tags: python, zip

I am running a python program (v2.7) which zips output so that it can be emailed.

Usually this works as expected, but occasionally the zipped file is so huge that the machine runs out of disk space. Yet when I zip the file manually using the finder, it works fine.

In this case, the 6MB file gets zipped down to a 1.6MB file using the finder, but the python zip method generated a 20GB file. Here is the code where the zipping is happening:

```
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfilename,"w",zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    for f in os.listdir("."):
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(f,"*final*"):
            zip.write(f)
    zip.close()
```

Is there a way to fix this or at least avoid generating a gigantic file?

Comment: don't `zip.write(f)` if `f` is a directory, a link, `zipfilename`. You could use `os.path.isfile()` and `os.path.samefile()`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you maybe create that zip file in the same directory and the program is then trying to add the zipfile itself to the zip file?

Comment: The zip file is created in the same directory, but usually the zipping works successfully. For example, a file from the previous day of 9.6M was zipped down to 2.6M.

Comment: @user1086476: The effects might depend on the (arbitrary) order in which `listdir()` returns the file names. You should definitely make sure that the zip file itself is not in the files that you try to add.

Answer (score 0):

Its Linux?, i think you are including hidden files and folders?